# Flutter appauth Invalid parameter: redirect_uri

Tags: flutter, keycloak, appauth

I have local instance of keylcoak and I am trying to connect my flutter app to it and for that I am following the [this tutorial](https://auth0.com/blog/get-started-with-flutter-authentication/) but I got stuck on this redirect_uri issue.

In android's build.gradle I have added the following piece to default config:

```
  applicationId = 'com.my.example_app'
  manifestPlaceholders = [
        'appAuthRedirectScheme': 'com.my.example_app'
  ]
```

In the code I have:

```
    const REDIRECT_URI = 'com.my.example_app://login-callback';
    //some code in between
    final AuthorizationTokenRequest req = AuthorizationTokenRequest(
    CLIENT_ID,
    REDIRECT_URI,
    allowInsecureConnections: true,
    issuer: ISSUER,
    discoveryUrl: DISCOVERY_URL,
    scopes: SCOPES);
    final AuthorizationTokenResponse result = await appAuth.authorizeAndExchangeCode(req);
```

I was also trying different configs on keycloak side:
[image]

So when I press `login` and it redirects me to the keycloak page but all I see is:

[image]

Does anyone know what is the proper redirect uri value here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your code is that your applicationId and appAuthRedirectScheme contains '_' character which is invalid for an URL, so I would suggest to change app package name to not contain capitalized or other characters other than '.', and it should work

Comment: also check the link for more informatio:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/65636066/9281109